# Difference between SwingWorker and SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, swing, multithreading

I need to run some method in Swing application in separate thread. What is the difference between using SwingWorker and SwingUtilities.invokeLater. Which one should I use to run a thread in Swing application? I couldn't find exact info in the tutorial at

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is used if you have something that must run in the EDT.

If you have a long-running task, you instead need to use a `SwingWorker`, since it does not run on the EDT and therefore does not cause the GUI to freeze while it runs.

Comment: thank you. this is generaly what i thought, but i needed confiramtion

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you would want to:

- use `SwingWorker` when you need to monitor the status of a long-running background process
- use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` if you just want a short task to run but do not need feedback on it. Sort of like a fire-and-forget. Just keep in mind it will run in the AWT event dispatching thread, so your application would not be getting any events handled while the task is running.